# c++ entering values two times instead of one

Tags: c++

I have to solve this " create class for describing triangle and trapeze with ability to return values and finding S of the figures.. declare function which allows comparing S of the both figures.. in main function declare object triangle and trapeze and compare their areas .. " - im trying to translate it from Bulgarian to English sorry if its not translated correctly ..
**Anyways I came up with a solution, but when it asks me to enter value for trapeze x2 times and I can't understand why...** it always takes the first 3 entered numbers but I want it to ask for input only once .. sorry if the answer is obvious
[image]

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  compare S of 2 figures
//
//  Created by Георгиос Семерджиев on 17/05/22.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Trap // trap class with declared functions inside
{
protected:
    double a, c, h;
    void setValueTrap();
public:
    Trap();
    void Print();
    virtual double S();
};  // end trap class

class Triangle : public Trap  // triangle class with declared function for finding s() print and setting value
{
    double b;
    void setValueTriangle();
public:
    Triangle();
    void Print();
    virtual double S();
    double p(); // returning P/2
}; // end triangle class

// trap functions ...

Trap:: Trap()
{
    setValueTrap();
}

void Trap::setValueTrap()      // trap input function
{
    cout << "Trap enter a = "; cin >> a;
    cout << "Trap enter c = "; cin >> c;
    cout << "Trap enter h = "; cin >> h;
    cout << endl;
}

double Trap::S() // trap calculating and returning s()
{
    return ( (a+c) * h ) / 2;
}

void Trap::Print() // printing S() for trap
{
    cout << "Trap S = " << S();
    cout << endl;
}

// Triangle functions ..

Triangle::Triangle():Trap()
{
    setValueTriangle();
}

void Triangle::setValueTriangle()  // setting value for triangle a,b,c
{
    cout << "Triangle a = "; cin >> a;
    cout << "Triangle b = "; cin >> b;
    cout << "Triangle c = "; cin >> c;
    cout << endl;
}

double Triangle::p() // returning P / 2 = p
{
    return (a+b+c) / 2;
}

double Triangle::S() // calculating S() of triangle
{
    return sqrt(p() * (p() - a) * (p()-b) * (p()-c));
}

void Triangle::Print()
{
    cout << "Triangle S = " << S();
    cout << endl;
}

// creating function to compare Trap S() and Triangle S()

bool Compare (Trap *F1, Trap *F2)
{
    return F1 -> S() < F2 -> S();
} // compare function


int main()
{
    Trap* trap = new Trap();
    Triangle* triangle = new Triangle();
    
    trap -> Print(); triangle -> Print();
    cout << endl;
    
    if (Compare(trap, triangle))
        cout << "the Trap S < Triangle S.." << endl;
    
    else
    {
        cout << "The Trap S > Triangle S.." << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first one is for the `trap`, the second one is for the `triangle`

Comment: There's no reason to use pointers and `new` here. You can create a `Trap` object simply with the definition `Trap trap;`.

Comment: Your program is leaking memory. Don't use raw pointers.

Comment: Btw, should a `Triangle` really have all the member variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `h`? Is a `Triangle` really a type of `Trap`?

Comment: well I thought about that too, but the teacher showed us similar type of task and I was just trying too look from her solution.. and she also used raw pointers, she is also calling the first object constructor 2 times.. im kinda confused rn :X

Comment: By the way: Your output ignores the equality case; complement of > is <=, not <...

Comment: aw, forgot about that, thnx

Comment: Teachers are pretty often not up to date of languages. *If* you need to use pointers prefer modern smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, depending on requirements). And if raw pointers are unavoidable for whatever reason then for every `new` foresee the corresponding `delete` right from the start. Anything else *will* lead to memory leaks...

Comment: @Aconcagua thnx ! im supposed to add delete trap; delete triangle; at the end of int main() right ?

Comment: @Geo48 Did the _"similar type of task"_  use a base class in which not all member variables was used in the derived class? Yes, you should `delete` them ... or better, use a smart pointer, like `unique_ptr` that does that automatically. In the example you've shown, you don't even need pointers. You could instantiate them as automatic variables as Someprogrammerdude suggested at the top.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No its same as this but instead area she finds perimeter and instead trapeze and triangle she uses rhombus and circle if I remember well

Comment: @TedLyngmo then why would she even use pointers, bcs its in the polymorphism topic or ?

Comment: @Geo48 Yes, pointers are good if you need to store and access your instances via base class pointers - but your base class doesn't have a `virtual` destructor, so storing them as base class pointers is off the table. Also, your `Print` function is not `virtual` so calling that from a base class pointer would only call the base class `Print`

Comment: I'd rework this setup. Find the common attributes **all** your shapes will have and put those in your base class. Then inherit and _add_ attributes in the derived classes if needed. If a base class has an attribute that you don't need in the derived class - it's probably not the correct base class.

Comment: will do, thnx y'all for spending your time on explanations! appreciate it!

Comment: @Geo48 There are several options you can handle the memory leak. Unless specific implications make it impossible (like when using polymorphism or when the objects might get too large for the stack – the latter a pretty rare case) then simplest is to create the objects right on the stack: `Trap trap; Triangle triangle;` such objects will be destructed *implicitly* as soon as they run out of scope. The same applies if you use smart pointers, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Trap> trap = new Trap();` or alternatively `auto trap = std::make_unique<Trap>();`.

Comment: Only if you have a good reason for avoiding the smart pointers I'd go with raw pointers (note: you might use them when passing the objects to functions that won't take ownership) then you should consider them. And yes, in that case you need to explicitly delete the objects, just as you mentioned for your trap and triangle objects...

Comment: @Aconcagua Tried redoing the solution but I get this error now.. https://pastebin.com/MjJy831 https://ibb.co/WfcFx8C

Comment: @Geo48 This kind of error typically occurs if you have forgotten to implement one of the virtual functions (or to make it pure virtual), or maybe you try to `dynamic_cast` while  `ShapeBase` doesn't have RTTI information at all because of not having any virtual members (then add at least a virtual destructor).

Comment: @Aconcagua I tried looking somewhere in the internet how should that be done but couldn't fix it myself, whenever you have some time I'd be really, really grateful if you show me how to do that on my code up there ^.. Even if not, one more thnx for all the help !

Comment: @Geo48 Minimalistic [example](https://godbolt.org/z/YscoPsG1x) – illustrates, too, how constructors are called one after another (your original problem; note double output, once from `Triangle t;`, then again from `new Triangle()`)... Not sure what you need else. Not sure either if that `BaseShape` helps you out at all – do you have siblings of `Trap` in class hierarchy (at very least in mind, so conceptually only)? If not, doesn't appear justified to me. Instead add an explicit virtual destructor to `Trap` class...

Comment: For completeness: [Extended example](https://godbolt.org/z/eabrba8xM) illustrating calling of destructors in inverse order – and order of destruction of elements relative to one another... Feel free to play around a bit with for discovering further details ;) (Side note: If you keep your memory management right, i.e. no memory leaks, then number of times objects are destructed needs to be equal to number of objects created.)

Comment: You are asked for entering Trap values twice because the 2nd time it was called during "Triangle initialization". The constructor of Triangle calls the base class constructor additionally. 

I'd suggest to remove calling the setValue() methods from the constructors - and instead call them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `Triangle` constructor you have:

```
Triangle::Triangle():Trap()
{
    setValueTriangle();
}
```

That will explicitly invoke the `Trap` constructor which read input. Then you will read the input for the triangle.

It's often not a good idea to read input in a constructor. It's usually better to only do basic initialization in the constructor and then get input using the fully constructed object.

---

Note that even if you don't have the explicit invokation of the `Trap` constructor, this will happen implicitly.

Comment: I don't like telling beginners "it's a bad idea to do X" because they usually don't understand why, and then don't do X even when it's a good idea. I limit statements like that to the specific code under discussion, where X doesn't work.

Comment: I personally consider it (usually) even better way to do input and possibly parsing *before* constructing any object (unless the object is intended for exactly that purpose).

Answer (score -1):

`Triangle` inherits from `Trap`, and both of their constructors are called when constructing `Triangle` object. To avoid this set up a virtual function `setValue` and call it **only** in `Trap` constructor.

Comment: Calling a virtual function in the constructor of Trap calls the Trap version of the function.

Comment: if I call a virtual function in trap for setting the values, won't I need to set value h in triangle also value b in trap where I don't need them ?

Comment: @Geo48 Honestly, forget about that idea. When `Trap` is constructed it is still *only* a `Trap` object, thus as mentioned already not the overridden version of Triangle is called, but the one of `Trap`. Thus if virtual or not, it will always be the same version that's called...

Comment: @Geo48 *If* you want to work with virtual functions then *first* construct the object, *then* call the virtual function upon, e.g. like `Triangle t; t.setValue();`.